# Non negative least square on some coefficient

Tags: python, least-squares, constraint

Non negative least square solves

$$
y = \alpha^T x \\
s.t. \forall i,~ \alpha_i \geq 0
$$

However, I would like to apply the non negativity constraint only on some coefficient, say only the $\alpha_i,~ \forall i \in \mathcal{S}$.

This is not possible using scipy's `nnls` function. However, I think I can solve the problem by using `nnls` with the following trick:

$$
y = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \alpha_i x_i + \sum_{i \notin \mathcal{S}} \beta_i x_i - \sum_{i \notin \mathcal{S}} \gamma_i x_i \\
s.t.~\forall i~, \alpha_i \geq 0, \beta_i \geq 0, \gamma_i \geq 0
$$

but this is hacky. Do you know any over way to implement this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with the extra parameters will be problematic as multiple values for the coefficients will provide a same solution (the solution won't be unique).

Non-negative least squares regression is often solved by an [active set method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active-set_method) that updates in steps the active constraints (see for instance [How do Lawson and Hanson solve the unconstrained least squares problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511107/)). In those steps various regular least squares estimates are computed for different active sets. Those steps will fail with your approach because of the multiple solutions (you will get some errors during the computations like non-invertible matrices).

An alternative nnls for Python (aside from Galen's response) could be [scipy.optimize.lsq_linear](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear), which allows setting individual constraints and uses an active set method.

Comment: In the end, I prefered your solution as `lsq_linear` method of scipy was a clearer and most easy to use alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of multiple linear regression in which some of the variables are unbounded while others are bounded. I'm going to have ten unbounded parameters and ten non-negative parameters in this example. The quick gist is to use `scipy.optimize.Bounds` in an optimizer that supports this argument such as `'trust-constr'`, along with the insight that it allows the use of `np.inf`. You just set some of the bounds to be `-np.inf` and `np.inf` for the unbounded parameters, and set the bounds to be `0` and `np.inf` for the non-negative parameters.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds

np.random.seed(2022)

bounds = Bounds([-np.inf] * 10 + [0] * 10, [np.inf] * 20)
x = np.random.normal(size=100 * 20).reshape(100, 20)
true_a = np.arange(1,21)
true_y = x @ true_a + np.random.normal(size=100)
a0 = np.random.normal(size=20)

def f(a):
    y_hat = x @ a
    resid = true_y - y_hat
    lsq = np.mean(np.power(resid, 2))
    return lsq
    

result = minimize(f, x0=a0, method='trust-constr', bounds=bounds)

print(result.x)
```

Note that the last line accesses `results.x` rather than `results.a`because `x` is priviliged in `scipy.optimize`'s programming to be the parameter. But this prints a result for the optimized vector of parameters `a` as hoped. Here is the printout for this seed:

```py
[ 0.9363189   2.01708136  3.07371156  4.03469035  4.97227273  5.91210627
  6.86926581  8.05433955  8.83633234  9.93401828 10.96973645 12.05863185
 12.95428506 13.9473809  14.93419422 16.05477142 17.13887755 18.37746539
 19.05598047 19.78565871]
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the underlying algorithm? Is it equivalent to nnls in the case when I set `[0, np.inf] `to all? Is it derivative free?

Comment: It is one of several trust region methods available in `scipy.optimize`. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#trust-region-constrained-algorithm-method-trust-constr) say their implementation is based on [Lalee *et al* 1998](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/PDFfiles/etr.pdf) and [Byrd *et al* 1997](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/PDFfiles/nitro.pdf). I don't know which equivalence relation you are referring to, but I do not know any related results offhand anyway.

Comment: At a glance in the papers I see gradients, so I suspect it is not derivative free, but you can read the papers I linked to check more carefully.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that I dislike Scipy/Python, it is often difficult to find out what the underlying method is and the explanations of approaches are very superficial (little detail) with only references to articles that require a lot of research effort. In the end, this approach of using `minimize` is not so great because it approaches specific linear least squares problem as a general minimization problem.

Comment: SciPy has a [GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) where you can bring attention to issues and propose changes to the documentation.

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/0badccb96162a88732a7b52a1c644b79) shows that `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` is very close in results to `minimize(method="trust-constr")`.

Comment: @Galen are they also equally fast? The `minimize` function is not directly solving the least squares problem as an ordinary least squares problem and instead uses something like gradient descent, isn't it?

Comment: I have also had success with using an optimization method without bounds or constraints and adding a penalty term. The problem is that it can be a little tricky to figure out the best penalty term. For instance, I just tested optimizing $||y-Mx||$ for a two-dimensional matrix $M$ with a penalty term given by $f(x<0) = \frac{1}{2}(1-tanh(10x), f(x>0) = 0$. Compared to a brute-force grid search with a resolution of 0.01, it was about 1% off from the correct solution for the first coordinate and about $10^{-5}$ off from the correct solution (zero) in the second coordinate with L-BFGS-B.

Comment: But using the tanh function instead of 0 for $x>0$ makes it much less accurate, using $x^2$ for $x<0$ makes it much less accurate, using a larger or smaller weight (15 seemed decent) can make it much less accurate, and so forth.

Comment: Obviously that is for all non-negative constraints, but I imagine it could work for only some of the coordinates being non-negative.

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/a40d5cdd808d2c329f1f1e954153522a) shows that `lsq_linear` is about 0.15 seconds faster than `minimize(method="trust-constr")`. The former is less than a millisecond while the latter is about 150 milliseconds. Human temporal perception is around 10-15 milliseconds, so the difference is perceivable. That also makes the former approach subjectively instantaneous while the latter probably has a perceivable duration for most people. I expect `lsq_linear` will require less energy and scale better on this type of linear problem.

Comment: I was really surprised that the proposed function didn't take any derivative as input so I dug a little bit more. Actually, the proposed solution approximates the derivative with the finite difference method. It is possible to provide a derivative using the `jac=` argument of `minimize`.

Comment: @LucG that will make the function probably somewhat faster, but it is still an overkill to use some iterative gradient based optimization technique while there is a direct solution with OLS.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach would be using constrained minimization, applying the non-negativity constraints only to certain variables - along the lines of the python implementation provided in an answer to [How to include constraint to Scipy NNLS function solution so that it sums to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33385898/6151828).

Another trick is variable transformation that makes certain variables always non-negative, like $x=y^2$. One can then use any general purpose minimization routine.

The only problem with these approaches is that they will perform much slower than NNLS for a large number of variables - whether this is a constraint depends on the problem, the available computational capacities, and the programming language used.