How can Poisson data be split into signal and background components?
Ok, so my problem is as follows: I have data that is Poisson distributed, my model is that
$$ d_i \sim \text{Poiss}\left[\sum_j M_{ij} \theta_j\right] $$
I know want to find an estimator for the "population $\theta$". As an example, $M$ might represent a few signal peaks at known positions and known width over some background curve (eg polynomials).
My first attempt was first performing element-wise Bayesian inference $\hat{\lambda}_i \sim \Gamma[d_i, 1]$ and projecting that onto $\theta$ space using the pseudoinverse of $M$. For the point prediction this is essentially just a least square fit of the data. I was a little doubtful whether this makes sense though and in simulations found that it was slightly worse than a numeric solution of the MLE equation.
Next attempt was GLM, but the issue is that this ends up parameterising into "signal $\cdot$ background" rather than "signal + background". Additionally the posterior predictive standard error ends up being huge because it's $\approx \exp(M \hat{\mu_\theta}) \cdot M \hat{\sigma_\theta}$ so doing something like GLM to remove the background and then fitting just the signal seperately isn't feasible.
I also tried writing down the log likelyhood for the initial model, setting the gradient to 0 and trying to find an approximate solution to the equation$^*$ ending up with
$$ \left(M^T \text{diag}(d)^{-1} M\right)^{-1} \left(1+\sum_i M_i\right)$$. But this had worse performance than the least squares approach, even for relatively small count numbers like $d_i \approx 10$ where Poisson is very non-gaussian.
I also tried to tackle the simplified model of
$$ T = S + B_0 \quad, \quad S\sim\text{Poiss}[\lambda_s], B_i\sim\text{Poiss}[\lambda_b]$$ with $T$ and $B_1$ being availble as data and just barely managed to find a closed form for the posterior of $\lambda_s$, but this didn't lead anywhere for the general question.
At this point I am kind of lost what else I could try and fear that I'll have to make do with the least squares approach. But this seems like such a classic problem, surely there is a solution out there.
$^*$ : the approximation was a linear expansion in $\epsilon_i = \frac{(M\theta)_i}{b_i} - 1$

Next attempt was GLM, but the issue is that this ends up parameterising into "signal ⋅ background" rather than "signal + background". --- try changing your link function?

Specific instances, such as automatic or supervised identification of spectra peaks, are not only classic, there is a huge literature on them.  The specific problems you refer to have all been solved in many ways, with details depending on the nature of the spectrum and your application (such as targeted identification or generic identification).  It would therefore help--and is likely essential--for you to focus on one aspect of your analysis and provide more specifics.

@whuber Thanks! Yeah it's an xray spectrum with characteristic peaks like you guessed. but the issue is that eventually I wanted to move to more abstract parameters than the peak volumes or whatever. Recognising the peaks was never really an issue, but finding robust and performant error estimation turned out to be more difficult.

@Glen_b What exactly do you mean? like instead of d ~ Poiss(exp(M$\theta$)) using  d ~ Poiss(M$\theta$) ? That's what I was comparing the other methods to, but I can't find a closed form approximation that makes sense and numerically solving every time is not tractable. Also, in that case I might as well do a direct numerical bayesian thing.

I happen to know a lot about this application ;-).  What puzzles me is your assertion that the GLM yields a multiplicative model of signal and background rather than an additive one. That's not the case. The other puzzling aspect is the formulation as a strictly linear model (in the parameters). That assumes you know very precisely the peak widths and locations, but AFAIK that's never the case due to small amounts of drift and noise in measuring the x-ray energies. The standard formulations all use nonlinear models, as I suggest at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628497.

BTW, please don't infer too much from the question I linked to, because it concerns somebody else's formulation of the problem assuming iid Gaussian errors in the channel counts (and uses a simulated gamma ray spectrum with a Lorentz rather than Gaussian peak).  It's readily reframed in terms of a conditional Poisson response.  Also, I think it's almost always better to regularize or otherwise more gently deal with physical limitations rather than imposing hard constraints (and so I find your Bayesian approach appealing).

@whuber Thanks! I'll read more into that!
Re: GLM - the reason why I suggested this is become the "standard" poisson GLM I found used d ~ Poiss(exp($M\theta$)) and thus when expanding out the sum in the exp you get a multiplicative relation between the rows of M,
Re: Linearity - In our previous work we found that they are very well controlled, the energy resolution of the detectors is very reliable and we can calibrate them pretty precisely.
Re: Bayes - in the end one of the goals is to get a good approximation of Bayes factors for different models to do multi-model rather than NH tests,

Thanks.  That's exactly what @glen_b was getting at: if you don't use the logarithmic link function you can do an additive Poisson regression.  I have performed this "manually" by optimizing the likelihood with a general-purpose optimizer--but only one peak at a time, in what I referred to as a "targeted" identification.  If you don't know which elements are in your sample and you're looking for anything, the problem is harder (and it's difficult to get really low detection limits).  That's why I requested more specifics in my initial comment.

@whuber ah now I get it! Yeah my issue with manually optimizing was just that I already had a few other expensive techniques that give me full posteriors, so having to solve an optimisation problem at ~ms to s time per spectrum was redundant to me.
Yes I do generally know which elements are there, or at least have a list of candidates. Though sometimes their peaks have significant overlap, eg the L peaks of W, Au, Pb. I'm basically trying to solve two problems, one is quanitifying the signal with reliable errors the other is developing robust testing that's better than just a NH probability

I made good progress in those directions through likelihood profiling, plotting the maximum likelihood conditional on fixing one or two parameters.  I believe there is much that can be learned still.  For instance, I discovered that with the instrument I was studying, there is positive serial correlation in the Poisson noise among the channels (the coefficient is always around 0.15 to 0.20).  Another issue of interest is that detection and quantification often involves several peaks, such as the L-alpha and L-beta peaks of lead, whose amplitudes will be strongly correlated.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
