# How to perform Least Squares with constraints on a subset of the model coefficients?

Tags: least-squares, constrained-regression

For solving an unconstrained LS regression 
$$\hat{y}=w_1.x_1+w_2.x_2+w_3.x_3+w_4.x_4 + \epsilon$$
I use the following normal equation:
$$W^*=(X^{\top}X)^{-1}X^{\top}Y $$

If I want to introduce a constraint on all of the parameters, e.g. the ridge regression $w_i^2<c$, for $\forall i$, I can formulate the Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L(W,\lambda)} = (Y - XW)^2 - \lambda (W)^2.$$

and also obtain a matrix form solution, given by:
$$W^*=(X^{\top}X-\lambda I)^{-1}X^{\top}Y $$

The question is: how may I formulate the above equation if I only want to impose constraints on some of the coefficients, e.g. $w_1=w_2$ with $w=[w_1, w_2, ..., w_d]$?

I can get to the Lagrangian, which would be: 
$$ \mathcal{L(W,\lambda)} = (Y - XW)^2 - \lambda (w_1-w_2)$$ 
but I can't get to the matrix solution for $W^*$.

I'm searching for a manual solution (i.e. with no python or R code).
Thanks in advance and sorry for the not-rigorous notation.

Comment: With $w_1=w_2$, just look at the linear predictor $w_0+w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \dotsm = w_0 + w_1 (x_1+x_2) + \dotsm $! So jus remove one of them, and add the corresponding predictors.  Here is a similar but more complicated example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248779/linear-model-with-constraints-on-coefficients-in-terms-of-ratios/248898#248898

Comment: What could I do to impose a constraint that w1 should be "around" 1000 and w3 "around" 50?

Comment: Maybe a Bayes solution, with a prior distribution with mean of $W1$ 1000 and of $w3$ 50? and some prior variance expressing how certain you are about those restrictions. Or, not going that route, using regularization but with offsets in addition, that is , $w1$ is represented by `w1+offset(Id(50*w1))` in `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ridge is the exception, not the norm, in this case. Applying a quadratic term in the Lagrangian still allows for a closed solution of the regression, and is one of the reasons why Ridge is interesting. Using a different function to regularize will most likely not produce a closed form solution. As an example, L1-regularization, the LASSO, has no closed form solution for $W^*$.

While I could not show that your regularization has no closed form, I am persuaded that is does not; because this coupling of coordinates usually yields nasty results in matrix theory (see the uses of the Vandermonde determinant in Gaussian Random Matrices and you will see what I mean by nasty). This does not mean it is useless, just like LASSO is not useless, it just means that you should look for a numerical, iterative and algorithmic solution rather than a pretty closed form.